# p5.js Draw a box when the conditions are not met using an if statement

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

i have been pulling my hair out with this for few hours.I have to create shapes when the cursor is in a certain place using if statements, which i have completed. I also need to draw a shape if neither of the conditions are met, this i have only managed to half complete. IS anybody able to give some guidance on what i need to think about to complete the task?[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn8Eg.png)

```
function draw()
{
    // draw the image
    image(img,0,0);

    //Write your code below here ...

//91m distance dark circle  
if(dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585)<= 91)
{
    fill(0,139,139);
    ellipse(1491, 585,91 * 2, 91 * 2);

}
//Fish wholsalers   
if(mouseX > 1590 && mouseX < 1691
    && mouseY > 614 && mouseY < 691)
{
    fill(25, 25, 112)
    rect(1590,614,104,77) 

}
//neither position
if(dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585)>= 91 && (mouseX > 1690 && mouseX < 1590 && mouseY < 614 && mouseY > 691) )
{
    fill(124, 252, 0)
    rect(1564, 183, 322, 173 )  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use 2 variables.

Evaluate if the mouse is `in_range`:

```js
var in_range = dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585)<= 91;
```

Evaluate if the mouse is in bounds:

```js
var in_bounds = mouseX > 1590 && mouseX < 1691 && mouseY > 614 && mouseY < 691;
```

Draw the rectangles dependent on the conditions `in_range`,  `in_bounds` respectively `!in_range && !in_bounds`.

```js
var in_range = dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585)<= 91;
var in_bounds = mouseX > 1590 && mouseX < 1691 && mouseY > 614 && mouseY < 691; 

if (in_range)
{
    fill(0,139,139);
    ellipse(1491, 585,91 * 2, 91 * 2);
}

if (in_bounds)
{
    fill(25, 25, 112)
    rect(1590,614,104,77) 
}

if(!in_range && !in_bounds)
{
    fill(124, 252, 0)
    rect(1564, 183, 322, 173 )  
}
```

---

If you are not allowed to use variables:

The opposite of  `<` is `>=` and the opposite of `>` is `<=`.
The opposite of `A && B` is `!(A && B)` respectively `!A || !B`.
The opposite of `x > A && x < B` is `x >= A || x <= B`.

In your case that is:

```js
if (!(dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585) <= 91) &&
    !(mouseX > 1590 && mouseX < 1691 && mouseY > 614 && mouseY < 691))
{
    fill(124, 252, 0)
    rect(1564, 183, 322, 173 )  
}
```

Or

```js
if (dist(mouseX, mouseY,1491, 585) > 91 &&
    (mouseX <= 1590 || mouseX >= 1691 || mouseY <= 614 || mouseY >= 691))
{
    fill(124, 252, 0)
    rect(1564, 183, 322, 173 )  
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, im very limited as to how i can answer the question. And can only use the following commands:

  if()
  fill()
  rect()
  ellipse()
  dist()

Comment: Thank you so much, i don't know why i didn't consider or statements. in my mind they didn't fit but I've seen perfectly there use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like:

```
//91m dist dark circle
if( yourCondition )
{

    yourCode;

}

// Fish wholsalers
else if( yourOtherCondition )
{

    yourOtherCode;

}

// neither position
else
{

    yourOtherOtherCode;

}
```

Comment: Thanks,im very limited as to how i can answer the question. And can only use the following commands: if() fill() rect() ellipse() dist()

Comment: It seems that `yourCondition` and `yourOtherCondition` should be able to evaluate to `true` at the same time.

Comment: Aren't the `else` and `else if` doing different things?